# bzip2 error ubuntu 16.04 (xenial)

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, tar, bzip2, decompression

I downloaded a file from lynx sources site:

http://invisible-mirror.net/archives/lynx/tarballs/?C=M;O=D

Specifically this file: `lynx2.8.8rel.2.tar.bz2` (tried several from the site).

When I apply `tar xjf` to the file I receive the following error:

```
bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

However, if I use Ubuntu (16.04) "File" application all goes well. Any suggestions as to why that is the case?

Comment: *"when i apply tar xjf to the file"* - please post the exact command

Comment: tar xjf lynx2.8.8rel.2.tar.bz2 
bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check the md5sum of the file:

```
md5sum lynx2.8.8rel.2.tar.bz2 
b231c2aa34dfe7ca25681ef4e55ee7e8  lynx2.8.8rel.2.tar.bz2
```

And if this is correct *any* of the following commands should work without fail on a default installation of Ubuntu:

```
tar xvf lynx2.8.8rel.2.tar.bz2
bzcat -dk lynx2.8.8rel.2.tar.bz2 | tar xvf -
bzip2 -dck lynx2.8.8rel.2.tar.bz2 | tar xvf -
```

(The `j` option to call bzip2, which you have used in your own commandline, is not normally required by tar in modern versions.)

If the md5sum is *different* from the one I have given above this will indicate that there is something amiss with the download process and the archive itself rather than a problem with either the `tar` or `bzip2` applications...

**Note:**

If using lynx to download this particular file (which I believe you have been attempting): on my system, using Lynx Version 2.8.8rel.2 the following produced a good download when tested with `md5sum`:

```
lynx -source \
'http://invisible-mirror.net/archives/lynx/tarballs/lynx2.8.8rel.2.tar.bz2' \
> lynx2.8.8rel.2.tar.bz2
```

**References:**

- [With Lynx, how do I download a page, image, or program from the web to my account from the Unix command line prompt?](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aczi)
- [How to decompress a .bz2 file](https://superuser.com/questions/480950/how-to-decompress-a-bz2-file)

Comment: $ tar xvf lynx2.8.8rel.2.tar.bz2 
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: bzip2 --version
bzip2, a block-sorting file compressor.  Version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010.

Comment: correct previous comment. should be: $ tar xjvf lynx2.8.8rel.2.tar.bz2

Comment: @amalafrida What happens with: `bzcat -dk lynx2.8.8rel.2.tar.bz2 | tar xvf -` ? This is a simple variation of `bzip2 -dck lynx2.8.8rel.2.tar.bz2 | tar xvf -` and might work around the odd problem you are experiencing...

Comment: bzcat -dk lynx2.8.8rel.2.tar.bz2 | tar xvf reports:
tar: Old option 'f' requires an argument.
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
bzcat: lynx2.8.8rel.2.tar.bz2 is not a bzip2 file.

Comment: @amalafrida You have left off the final `-` which is the signal to tar to use the input coming through the pipe :) But sounds like bzcat is failing anyway. Check the md5sum for the file: `b231c2aa34dfe7ca25681ef4e55ee7e8  lynx2.8.8rel.2.tar.bz2` on my system

Comment: ok. that solves it. checked md5sum on my file. did not match yours. downloaded (wget), ran md5sum, got match, tar xf ... works fine. however, exceedingly curious ... navigated to http://invisible-mirror.net/archives/lynx/tarballs/lynx2.8.8rel.2.tar.bz2 and downloaded via my lynx browser connection ... same error! would like to track that problem down. take it up with lynx developers??? any advice? in any case, problem solved (sorta). thanks much for your help. new to ubuntuhelp. do i upvote or mark as solved?

Comment: @amalfrida Mark as solved and upvote if you are especially pleased :). Sorry I did not think of the md5sum solution earlier but it took me to bzcat which I have not met before, so I have learnt something new! Don't report to the developers as I suspect it is not a problem at their end...

Comment: @amalafrida I tested with lynx and achieved a good download, added the detals to my answer...